# Converting text file with spaces between CR & LF

Tags: text-files, line-endings

I've never seen this line ending before and I am trying to load the file into a database.

The lines all have a fixed width. After the CSV text which contains the data (the length varies line-by-line), there is a CR followed by multiple spaces and ending with LF. The spaces provide the padding to equalize the line width.

```
Line1,Data 1,Data  2,Data 3,4,50D20202020200A
Line2,Data 11,Data 21,Data 31,41,510D2020200A
Line3,Data12,Data22,Data 32,42,520D202020200A
```

I am about to handle this with a stream reader / writer in C#, but there are 40 files that come in each month and if there is a way to convert them all at once instead of one line at a time, I would rather do that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line-by-line processing of a stream doesn't have to be a bottleneck if you implement it at the right point in your overall process.

When I've had to do this kind of preprocessing I put a folder watch on the inbound folder, then automatically pick up each file and process it upon arrival, putting the original into an archive folder and writing the processed file into another location from which data will be parsed or loaded into the database. Unless you have unusual real-time requirements, you'll never notice this kind of overhead. If you ***do*** have real-time requirements, this issue will pale in comparison to all the other issues you'll face with batched data files :)

But you may not even have to go through a preprocessing step at all. You didn't indicate what database you will be using or how you plan to load the data, but many databases do include utilities to process fixed-length records. In the past, fixed-format files came with every imaginable kind of bizarre format (and contained all kinds of stuff that had to be stripped out or converted). As a result those utilities tend to be very efficient at this kind of task. In my experience they can easily be at least an order of magnitude faster than line-by-line processing, which can make a real difference on larger bulk loads.

If your database doesn't have good bulk import processing tools, there are a number of many open-source or freeware utilities already written that do pretty much exactly what you need. You can find them on GitHub and other places. For example, **NPM replace** is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace) and **zzzprojects findandreplace** is [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/findandreplace).

For a quick and dirty approach that allows you to preview all the changes as you develop a more robust solution, many text editors have the ability to `find and replace in multiple files`. I've used that approach successfully in the past. For example, here's the window from NotePad++ that lets you use RegEx to remove or change whatever you like in all files matching defined criteria.

[image]

Comment: You have some good thoughts here. I want to handle the process programatically, rather than converting them one by one in a text editor. And you're right that the line-by-line approach need not be a bottleneck.

My hope, however, was to convert the file from Mac to Windows (or whatever this file type is) without having to do a lot of coding.

Thanks for the well thought out answer.